# bundler: not executable: bin/rails in rails production while using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I'm using whenever gem for cronjobs in rails application - production.
I'm getting an error `bundler: not executable: bin/rails`

scheduler.rb

```
every 15.minute do
 runner 'TestJob.perform_later()'
end
```

crontab

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/my-app/releases/20190719103116 && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''TestJob.perform_later()'\'''
```

but when i run `/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/my-app/releases/20190719103116 && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''TestJob.perform_later()'\'''` in my bash replacing `bin/rails` with just `rails` this work fine.How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it via a rake task:

**config/schedule.rb**

```rb
every 15.minutes do
  rake 'testing:run_tests'
end
```

**lib/tasks/testing.rake**

```rb
namespace :testing do
  desc 'Run tests'
  task run_tests: :environment do
    TestJob.perform_later
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you this worked... do u know why the command included bin/rails earlier?

Comment: You're welcome! This is how the job type `runner` is defined in whenever

https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types

Answer (score 4):

**Quick Answer**

With the intent of still using the original `runner` job type, simply add this to your **schedule.rb**:

```
set :runner_command, "rails runner"
```

**Long Answer**

The documentation isn't so clear about it, but you can see the default `runner` job type being set as such in Whenever's [/lib/whenever/setup.rb](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/setup.rb#L18):

```
job_type :runner, "cd :path && :bundle_command :runner_command -e :environment ':task' :output"
```

In that same file you can see that this `:runner_command` setting is set with:

```
set :runner_command, case
  when Whenever.bin_rails?
    "bin/rails runner"
  when Whenever.script_rails?
    "script/rails runner"
  else
    "script/runner"
  end
```

So by default your cron command will be created using `bin/rails runner` unless you overide it with the above answer.